# Primes written as the sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory

A well known result due to Fermat states that any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be written as the sum of two squares,$\,$ $p = a^2 + b^2$ .$\,$ We can define a set $\,A\,$ by collecting together all the $a$'s and $b$'s  which arise in this way (ignoring multiplicity).$\,$ Examples include:$\;$ $5 = 1^2 + 2^2$,$\;$$13 = 2^2 + 3^2$,$\;$$17 = 1^2 + 4^2$,$\;$$29 = 2^2 + 5^2$,$\;$and $\,$$37 = 1^2 + 6^2$. $\;$From these examples we see that $\,A\,$ begins with $\;A = \,${$\,$$1,2,3,4,5,6, ...$$\,$}$\;$.

Questions: $\;$ 1) Does the set $\,A\,$ coincide with the set of all natural numbers?

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$2) If not or if this is not known, is there at least a good lower bound for the density of$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$$\;$$\;$ the set$\,A\,$?

Thanks.

Comment: For (2), the number of elements of $A$ up to $y$ is at least $(1+o(1)) y/\sqrt{2\log y}$. This follows from the fact that all the primes up to $y^2$ that are $1\pmod4$ have to have a representation from $A\cap[1,y]$, if $a(y) = \#(A\cap[1,y])$, then we must have $\binom{a(y)}2 \ge \pi(y^2;4,1)  \sim y^2/4\log y$.

Answer (score 8):

1) is almost certainly true, though it does not seem to be a known result.

It is equivalent to show that every vertical line in the Gaussian integers contains a Gaussian prime.  There are many similar results along these lines, such as Tao's result that [the Gaussian primes contain arbitrarily shaped constellations](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501314).

In fact, it is likely that every vertical line contains infinitely many primes, but this would imply [Landau's fourth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems), and so it's certainly difficult.

Since it is frequently just as difficult to show that a sequence contains one prime as it is to show that it contains infinitely many, I would not be optimistic that this conjecture will be resolved anytime soon.

---

There may be a way to get a nice answer to 2) using known results.  For example, a standard density theorem is that the Gaussian primes are distributed evenly through sectors, which might lead to a lower bound on the density of their $x$-coordinates.

Comment: Nice answer! Interesting that your point "that every vertical line in the Gaussian integers contains a Gaussian prime" remains unresolved, is among the impediments to showing that [Gaussian prime spirals](http://mathoverflow.net/q/91423/6094) always close.

Answer (score 3):

2) By looking at [this derivation](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=72787&messageID=323445), there are asymptoticaly $2n^2/\log n$ Gaussian primes in the circle $|z|<n$, and so, in the square $0<\Re z,\Im z<n$ there are at least (asymptoticaly) $n^2/2\log n$ Gaussian primes. Hence, by pigeonhole principle, at least $n/2\log n$ abscissas out of first $n$ contain at least one Gaussian prime.

This is a very crude lower bound, but it's better than nothing.